# entering text into UI textfield by pressing return button

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextfield

let's say I want to enter some data into text field, text for example, I want to press done or return button in keyboard to enter data into UI text field.

how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as simple as using the `UITextFieldDelegate` to process when the return key has been pressed.

So you can adopt that protocol, assign the delegate on your `UITextField` and then process data in the delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing:` when the return key is pressed. The delegate method I mentioned can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:). Make sure you have enabled the processing of the return key by returning true from `textFieldShouldReturn:`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without implementing `UITextFieldDelegate`. You can add "target" for your `UITextField` which will call a method as user returns. Something like this:

```
    func init(){
        //Initialize everything else

        textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldReturned", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
    }

    //This method will be called after user "returns".
    //Note: Name this method whatever you like, just make sure it's
    //the same name you pass to 'addTarget' method as 'action:' parameter
    func textFieldReturned(){
        textField.resignFirstResponder() //Hides keyboard

        //Do everything you need after user presses "Done" button
    }
```